# ¿Cómo se dice, "How's it going"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, saludos

En inglés, se puede utilizar la expresión, "How's it going?" como una manera de preguntar cómo está alguien.

La frase es informal y tiene un significado similar al "¿Cómo estás?"

Sin embargo, cuando lo comprobé en el Traductor de Google, tradujo la frase "How's it going?" como "¿Cómo va todo?"

¿Es esa traducción la correcta y comúnmente usada?

Comment: Sí. En inglés muchas frases omiten complementos indirectos que en español se encuentran presentes: how is it going -> cómo (te) va eso, traducido literalmente, o como dices tú, etc. Todas sirven

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sí, es correcta. Para expresiones como "how is it going", "how are you doing" o simplemente "how are you" de manera informal, se puede decir:

- ¿Cómo estás?
- ¿Qué tal estás?
- ¿Cómo va (todo)?
- ¿Qué tal?
- ¿Qué tal va todo?
- ¿Qué tal andas?
- ¿Cómo andas?
- ¿Qué hay?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest expression is probably ¿Cómo te va? but ¿Cómo va todo? is also okay. Both of them use the word "va" to convey the sense of "going." ¿Cómo estás? is also often used, but that has more of a sense of how ARE you, as opposed to how are things GOING?

Comment: It's "¿cómo te/le va?", "¿cómo va?" or "¿cómo va todo?". "¿Cómo se va?" means "how do you go/how one goes (to that place)".

Answer (score 1):

Mis amigos de Chile me dicen:

> ¿Cómo andas?
>
> ¿Cómo tay?
>
> ¿Cómo estai?

Comment: Otro chilenismo: "¿Qué onda?".

Comment: Mexicanismo (Norteño): "¿Qué hubo(le)?"

Answer (score 1):

Also quiúbole, que pasó, qué me cuentas, cómo te ha ido, cómo has estado (though this one might be strictly U.S. and border Spanish, I'm not sure, as it's a direct translation of How ya been), qué dices (this one also has other meanings, e.g. Whatcha think?) ... and there's probably lots more that I don't know about. So many ways to say it, just like in English. Depends where you are located. My examples are from Mexico. All colloquial of course. Utterly formal would be Como está usted? Much depends on the register, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

So many variations depending on where you are.

Puerto Rico/Carribean you may hear ¨¿cómo tú estás?¨

Colombia (and maybe other places, who knows?) you´ll hear ¨¿qué hay?¨ (literally ¨what is there?¨ and shortened to ¨qu´hay?¨) or ¨¿qué hubo/qu´hubo? (what was there?)

in Mexico it´s ¨¿Qué onda?¨ (what wave)

You could argue that these are closer to ¨what´s up?¨ but they´re close enough to ¨how´s it going?¨ in terms of their actual function and the responses they´ll get you.

Comment: "¿Qué hay?" would be more like "what's up".

Answer (score 0):

You could say it many ways like:

> ¿Cómo va?
>
> ¿Qué tal?
>
> ¿Cómo estás?
>
> ¿Qué hay?

¿Qué hay? means more of what's up?